# SQL Server MDF Files - How to back up

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here's the scenario:

We have a corporate website with three databases.  It's running SQL Server 2005.  The three databases are linked to MDF files.  Someone tried to directly copy / paste one of these MDF files that did some kind of lock on the file that caused a read-only error.  We fixed this by detaching / reattaching.

To prevent this again, we're looking to get copies of these databases to demote to our QA database.

What's the best way we can make copies without taking the corporate site down? I tried to search google and didn't come up with a decent way.  The databases are fairly small, and the worst case I can think of is just to shut down the SQL Server Service, then just copy the MDF's, then restart the service.  I'm assuming that's 10 seconds at the most downtime.

**[Please note anyone reading this, do not directly copy MDF files, make sure you at least take the DB offline or the DB can be locked]**

Comment: Sorry, I should have added, that the databases are not on the same network since it's hosted remotely, so we can't just move the data.  We wont be able to connect to the QA database.

Comment: Can't you just schedule backups?  Then move the backup files.

Comment: We can just simply force a backup (DataBase > Tasks > Backup) that wont have any effect on any users trying to access the DB, correct?

Comment: I've moved my answers out of the comments so I can articulate better.

Comment: Thank You.  We want to minimize any downtime on the site.  Fortunately, it's a relatively low traffic site.  I'm testing the different scenarios on our QA database.  Basically this site hasn't been touched in years and I'm trying to get it up to date with my limited SQL Server Administration knowledge.  Go ahead and post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: With a small, low traffic database, I bet you notice negligible impact during the taking of the backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to copy and locking the MDF files, just take backups of the database to the filesystem and then copy those off.

You ask whether users will be affected during a backup...

We can't say that there won't be "any" affect on the users because of course we are doing things with the database. However, backing up live databases is the norm. Generally, you would schedule the backup overnight or during a period of low use so that there is minimal disruption.

Check out this questions which has some good information provided:
https://serverfault.com/questions/100490/what-happens-during-a-live-sql-server-backup

Answer (score 2):

@dave, I suspect you are right, that DataBase > Tasks > Backup will work without interrupting user access to the database. I run the following command in a batch file to backup my database, and it doesn't block access while it's running. I should note that I'm not an expert with SQL Server; this is just what works for me.

> sqlcmd -S "MyHostName\sqlexpress" -Q "BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabaseName TO DISK = N'C:\path\to\backup.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'MyDatabaseName-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10"

Comment: Thanks David for your comment.  I'm like you, I've worked with SQL Server as a developer for years, but not much on the administration side.  With this new job that's Oracle based, they have a corporate site running off SQL Server that hasn't been touched in literally 4 years.  I get promoted to SQL Server expert and have to figure this out.  I figured it's better to ask on here than to guess.