# How to backup and restore localDb 2012 Database?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, backup

I try to backup my localDB file using `file.Copy()` method but it throws the following `IOException`:

> The process cannot access the file '.\DB.mdf' because it is being used by another process.

And when I try to do backup with the following script:

```
@"BACKUP DATABASE " + DatabaseName + " TO DISK = N'" + BackUpLocation + @"\" + BackUpFileName + @"'"
```

it throws the following `SqlException`:

> Database 'DB' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

My connection string is:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

What is the best way to do backup in this situation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299527/sql-server-mdf-files-how-to-back-up

Comment: Try to use the full path od your mdf as a database name in BACKUP command.

Comment: Thank you a lot Dare @VDohnal . Your comment worked for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the full path od your mdf (e.g. `C:\DATA\DB.MDF`) as the database name in your `BACKUP DATABASE` command.